# UITableViewController and TableView Height

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am inheriting my view controller from UITableViewController. I have a header (logo), content (uitableview) and now I want to display the footer (uitabbar). But for some reason UITabBar is not visible. The space is being occupied by the UITableView. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE 1:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.tabBar;
```

}

Comment: Without code we can't help you

Comment: There is no code my class simply inherits from UITableViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can put a `UITabBar` as a footer of a `UITableView`.

"footer of the tableView" meaning it won't be visible until you scroll your `UITableView` all way down past the last cell to then see the footer -- the header and footer of a tableView scrolls with the tableView content itself). Anyway in term of UX this seems very strange.

You probably want instead your `UITabBar` to always be visible at the bottom of your screen (and not being dependant of the scrolling of your `UITableView`). To do this, simply use a `UITabBarController`... that will then contain your `UITableViewController` (as the viewcontroller associated with one of its `UITabBarItem`)

[EDIT] See also Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW15) and its paragraph about TabBarControllers.

Comment: Actually here is what I did and it worked. I created a MasterViewController which divides the interface into three views header, content and footer. Then I injected the TabBar into the footer view and the tableview into the contentview. It works fine!

Comment: Yup. Strange use of UITabBar (you don't use the facilities provided by UITabBarController, automanaging the UIViewControllers associated with each TabBarItem) but should work anyway. Note that you did not need to  create a MasterViewController specifically for this (even if it is ok to do it too, even if a bit of overhead), you could have changed your ```UITableViewController``` to an ```UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>``` (which is basically what ```UITableViewController``` is, aside from the fact that its main view is directly the tableView)